# How to use the ceph rgw compression feature?

Tags: ceph

I'm a new developer and using ceph 12.0.2 which installed by rpm.

Now I want to test the new feature about rgw compression.I just follow the docs [here](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/wip-rgw-compression-doc/radosgw/compression/)

But I did not get the compression rate like that.The compression rate of pictures just 99.9%, almost non-compression.And the compression rates of 3 plugins(zlib, snappy, zstd) are same.

So, I wonder that I get a wrong way to use this feature.Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Pictures in JPG and PNG formats are already compressed.

They cannot be compressed any more by a generic lossless compression algorithm.